# Missing ) in argument lit

Tags: jquery

I'm getting a error message that says missing ) after argument list and not sure why.

```
function getInboxUnreadMessagesCount(displayElementID)
{
$.get(<?php echo base_url(); ?>'dashboard/getInboxUnreadMessagesCount', function(data)
{
    $messageCountJSON = data; 
    if(displayElementID != null && displayElementID != undefined && displayElementID != '')
{
    //$('#'+displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON);
    if(parseInt($('#'+displayElementID).text()) < parseInt($messageCountJSON))
    {
        $.jGrowl("You have received a new private message!", {theme : 'information'});
        $('#'+displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON).css({"display":"block"});
    }
    if(parseInt($messageCountJSON) == 0)
    {
        $('#'+displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON).css({"display":"none"});
    }
}
}, 'json');
}
```

Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: Because there is no ) after argument list? Post a bit more code, please.

Comment: Because the ) is indeed missing (of `$.get(`)

Comment: Opening 3 parentheses, closing 2. Could be a problem...

Comment: What's the result that the PHP outputs to the browser? Or is PHP giving you the error and not the browser?

Comment: Its the js giving me the error. Its reported in the Firebug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` output, exactly? I presume just a bare string, so you'll end up with code like:

```
$.get(http://somepath.com'dashboard/getInboxUnreadMessagesCount', function(){...});
```

Clearly that won't work. You probably want:

```
$.get('<?php echo base_url(); ?>/dashboard/getInboxUnreadMessagesCount', function(){...});
```

This way the base url will end up actually *inside* the path to `$.get`.

Comment: There's only one problem with that though I get this for the GET in the Firebug console.   
jquery.min.js (line 4)
404 Not Found
  207ms 
jquery.min.js (line 4)
GET http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/...();%20?%3E/dashboard/getInboxUnreadMessagesCount

Comment: Sorry, what? That link doesn't go anywhere and I'm not sure what you mean by you 'get this for the GET' in firebug. Basically you need to look at the source output by php, the actual code given to the browser, to see if it's been output correctly.